# Periodically updating text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a method getSpeed() that periodically calculates the speed travelled at between two LatLng points. At the moment I am just printing the results out to console, was wondering how to output it to a text box/feed on my web page?

```
//retrieve information from database
     downloadUrl("Map.php", function(data){
          var xml = data.responseXML;
          var allPoints = Array();
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

          for(var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                    allPoints[i] = point;
                }

            for(var i = 1; i <allPoints.length; i++){
                var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
                        allPoints[i], allPoints[i-1]);
                var speed = ((distance/1000)*60);
                        console.log(distance.toFixed(2)+'m at a speed of '+speed.toFixed(2)+'km/h');

                        if(speed < 8){
                            console.log('WARNING: SPEED IS LOW!');
                        }
           }


});
}
```

I also have a div defined as follows, which I am looking to use as my text box...

```
   <div id="log" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 100px; border: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; width: 500px; height: 500px;" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = distance.toFixed(2) + 
   'm at a speed of ' + speed.toFixed(2) + 'km/h';

if(speed < 8){
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<br />WARNING: SPEED IS LOW!';
```

We're looking up that `div` by its `id`, and replacing its contents.